# notices when dowloading files by SFTP with phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I get this errors when I try download files by SFTP using phpseclib:

> Notice: Invalid HMAC in /var/www/project1/include/sftp/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 1890
>
> Notice: Connection closed by server in
>   /var/www/project1/include/sftp/Net/SSH2.php on line 2017
>
> Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_DATA or SSH_FXP_STATUS in
>   /var/www/project1/include/sftp/Net/SFTP.php on line 1489

These errors occur when the file size is greater than 100kb and I
can´t to download the file.

Please, can somebody give me an idea or can help me to solve this problem?

PD. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of phpseclib are you using? Can you post logs? You can get the logs by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` and then, after you're done, `$ssh->getLog()`.

Comment: Thanks neubert. No, I can`t post logs. The version of phpseclib is 0.1.0

Comment: Oh wow. Upgrade now. I'm 99% sure that'll fix your problem. The latest version is 0.3.5. 0.1.0 was released almost six years ago :O